# What's a good structure for making games?

Tags: coding-style, structure

I'm starting game development, but I *really* want to avoid hacking together a step-by-step game. I'm thinking, what's a good system for handling all that goes on?

For example, I thought of making a menu class, that contains an array of objects for buttons in the menu, and then every game loop call update() on the menu, which in turn calls update() on all the buttons, passing user input and such along the way. Is this a good way to do it?

I'm trying to find structural techniques past the game loop, any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

(BTW I'm using c++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not that trivial, but let me try to give you a really simple answer. You need at minimum a core architecture where you can register several engines. Take a deep look into state machines and several software patterns. There have been really greate game dev books like the Game Programming Gems. Start reading an older book from André LaMothe. Read source code ie. from Half Life 2 that could be downloaded at some places.

It sure depends on the environment, C++ is best and could be the fastest way to write games but would you like to use DirectX or OpenGL, do you need Audio and advanced input? Do you want to start with the older WinApi? Nevertheless it always starts in a single point, the main loop. There your state machine should be initialized and all resource managers need to be set up. For graphical objects you need to think about a low level init, update, draw, release and destroy cycle. UI is built up on Graphics, Input and other parts. Don't start writing your own UI or you need to spend the next 2 years with it. You need a relational game model that describes the world you want to create.

To be honest, read a lot about patterns (like mvc), state machines, gpu pipelines and framework design. Read a lot of code from very talented people that open sourced it for us:)

By the way, what is a step by step game?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I didn't know HL2 was open source. By step-by-step, I meant manually writing code and editing the game loop to make something happen, as opposed to making a new class with a single registering call that hooks it in to the rest of the code.

Comment: HL2 isn't open source but you will find the code. It was back in 2003 when bad people have stolen the source from valve. But for us it's a really good place to learn the big picture of game architecture.